# Go return error along with interface from a function

Tags: go, interface

Is there a way to return error with an interface for a function in golang?

`func abc(ctx context.Context, call func() error) (interface{}, err) {`

Something like the above prototype? The requirement is that I pass a function which could take in multiple input data type and return that particular data type.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you think there is a problem to return an `interface{}` together with an `error`?

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

func return_something() (interface{}, error) {
    return 123, errors.New("this is an error")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(return_something())
}
```

`123 this is an error`

https://play.golang.org/p/qqy1-Tn0yBy

Just a note:
One of Go's creators Rob Pike once said that the empty interface is one of the most abused features of Go, and many SO problems are caused by it being used inappropriately. Make sure you have considered if an empty interface is really appropriate for your use case

Answer (score 0):

Yes your callback function could take multiple inputs and multiple return values. 
Try if function closure works for you.

[Closures](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/25)

This is one way of using callbacks, there are many ways of using it.

https://play.golang.org/p/_4dQwJ_jPSD

Try to map the functions in map and use it with key

Try to assign function to function type etc